# Validation error: "The field Body must be a string with a minimum length of 16 and a maximum length of 16384."

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-code-first, full-text-search

This is baffling me. Simple insert into an MS SQL 2016 DB of most records works except a large handful. Nothing obvious I can spot about these particular inserts. The error message seems pretty obvious yet the thing it's complaining about doesn't fail its validation:

```
"The field Body must be a string with a minimum length of 16 and a maximum length of 16384."
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[FullTextSearches] (
[Id]            INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[RecordId]      INT            NOT NULL,
[RecordType]    INT            NOT NULL,
[Title]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Body]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Accessibility] INT            NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.FullTextSearches] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
GO
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON [dbo].[FullTextSearches]
([Title] LANGUAGE 1033, [Body] LANGUAGE 1033)
KEY INDEX [PK_dbo.FullTextSearches]
ON [FTSCatalog];
```

Model:

```
public class FullTextSearch
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int RecordId { get; set; }
    public FtsRecordType RecordType { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [MaxLength]
    public string Body { get; set; }

    public int Accessibility { get; set; }
}
```

Code:

```
        // These two lines are a hack; should not be needed
        if (body.Length < 16) body += "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
        if (body.Length > 16382) body = body.Substring(0, 16382);

            [...]

                record = new FullTextSearch
                {
                    Accessibility = accessibility,
                    Body = body,
                    RecordId = recordId,
                    RecordType = type,
                    Title = title
                };
                try
                {
                    db.FullTextSearch.Add(record);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
                {
                    Logger.LogError("FullTextSearchUtils.AddOrAmend exception (record " + recordId.ToString() + "): " + e.ToString());
                    Logger.LogError(body.Length.ToString());
                    foreach (DbEntityValidationResult res in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        foreach (var validationError in res.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Logger.LogError(String.Format("(cont.) Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage));
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Data being inserted:

```
accessibility 0
body: "<img src=\"http://www.xxx.co.uk/images/scotland.jpg\" border=\"0\" width=\"32\" height=\"22\" /> New releases! See <a href=\"index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;catid=3:newsflash&amp;id=69:xxx-scotland\">xxx Scotland</a>\n\r\nPeterborough meet details! See <a href=\"index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=70:peterborough-meet-details\">Peterborough Meet Details</a>\n"
title: "News 17th March 2010"
recordType: 0
recordId: 71
```

The only non-standard thing I can think of is the full-text indexing on the title and body fields. Yet the data is a string, and the length is within the constraints mentioned.

Now the string does contain mark-up - but other records with mark-up have inserted fine - for example:

```
<p style="text-align: left;"><img src="images/stories/frontpic2.jpg" border="0" alt="Panel" align="right" style="margin: 10px; border: 1px;" />
```

(I won't paste the full record due to length)

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: Stripped all HTML, BBCode, and non-printable characters out. Still failing on something as simple as "New releases! See Scotland   Peterborough meet details! See Peterborough Meet Details"

Comment: db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false; db.SaveChanges(); db.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true; Works but is not a solution.